# Why can't Java Applet ask only for specific permissions (eg, record audio)

Tags: java, security, permissions, applet

I'm building an audio recording applet, so it needs permission to record sound.  I signed the jar file, and now when I load the applet, a dialog pops up that says: "The applet from localhost is requesting access to your computer", and gives options for "Allow" or "Deny".  If I click allow, it can record sound.  But I'm disappointed that there seems to be no way to have it ask only for what it needs; something like "This applet would like permission to record sound. Allow or Deny"?  Is there a way to do this?

If not, any idea on the rationale for throwing away Java's fine grained security model with this all-or-nothing dialog box?  I could see a user allowing a site to record some sound, but not wanting to give it read/write access to the hard drive.

Comment: I am doing the same task, i have signed the jar file but it is not prompting me when I load the applet in browser. Any Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The JRE does not offer such fine grained permissions to standard applets.

An app. launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can get access to the local file system, the printer, and a number of other things in the way that you propose.  But those 'specific permission message' relaxations of the sand-box do not include things like getting screen-shots or capturing sound.